# array of strings as param tag in launch file

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to read an array of strings into my ros node. Here is the line in my launch file
`<param name="string_list" value="[this, is, a, string, array]"/>`

And here is the `nh.getParam()` call in my node

> ros::NodeHandle nh("~");`

> std::vectorstd::string string_list;

> nh.getParam("string_list", string_list);

I know that the param is there when I do a `rosparam list`. And i know the namespaces are correct since it works with a simple `int` param. But in this case with a vector of strings, when I read the `string_list` after the `getParam()` call, it is of 0 length

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281061/array-of-strings-as-param-tag-in-launch-file/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2018-01-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q194592, especially the answer by @peci1.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2018-01-28**:
`<arg name="string_list" default="[this, is, list]"/>`
`<rosparam param="string_list" subst_value="True">$(arg string_list)</rosparam>`

This shows the following error: requires the 'string_list' arg to be set